# Minimum of three random uniform variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I am studying for exam P, and am using a study guide with a solution. I am stuck on this problem and am unsure as to why my solution does not work. Any clarity I can get would be greatly appreciated. Here is the problem:

Three individuals are running a one kilometer race. The completion time for each individual is a random variable. 
is the completion time, in minutes, for person 
.

1
: uniform distribution on the interval [2.9, 3.1]

2
: uniform distribution on the interval [2.7, 3.1]

3
: uniform distribution on the interval [2.9, 3.3]

The three completion times are independent of one another. Find the probability that the earliest completion time is less than 3 minutes.

My solution was:
P(min(X1, X2, X3) <3) = P( X1<3 ∩ X2<3 ∩ X3<3 )

=P( X1<3). P(X2<3). P( X3<3 ).

and then using the Uniform CDF to get:
(1/2).(3/4).(3/4) = 9/32

The book, however, uses a different approach and hence gets a different answer.
their approach is as follows:

P(min(X1, X2, X3) <3) = 1- P(min(X1, X2, X3) > = 3).

= 1- P( X1>=3). P(X2>=3). P( X3>=3 ).

They then use 1-CDF to get an answer of ~ 0.91.
I fail to understand why we can just use the cdf directly as I did in my approach. All help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For the minimum to be less than $3$ it is required that $X_1<3$ **or** $X_2<3$ **or** $X_3<3$. So **or** and not **and** (as you state wrongly).

Comment: You've found the probability that **all** completion times are less than $3$ minutes. The probability that at least one completion time is less than $3$ minutes, is one minus the probability that all completion times are greater than $3$ minutes. So in reality you need to calculate $1-P(X_1>3)P(X_2>3)P(X_3>3)$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
P(min(X_1, X_2, X_3) <3) & = 1 - P(min(X_1, X_2, X_3) \geq 3)  
\end{align*}
If the minimum of the uniforms is greater than three, then the remaining uniforms are also greater than or equal to 3.
\begin{align*}
P(min(X_1, X_2, X_3) <3) & = 1 - P(min(X_1, X_2, X_3) \geq 3)  \\
& = 1 - P(X_1\geq 3, X_2 \geq 3,X_3 \geq 3) \\
& = 1 - P(X_1\geq 3) P(X_2 \geq 3) P(X_3 \geq 3) \\
& = 1 - [1-P(X_1 < 3)] [1-P(X_2 <3)][1 - P(X_3 < 3)] \\
&  \hspace{5cm} \vdots
\end{align*}
In your reasoning you are calculating that all the runners have a time less than 3, but we are only interested in the minimum being less than 3.